# Scrolling in android using Appium + Ruby

Tags: android, ruby, selenium, scroll, appium

I am trying to scroll through the android app to find a specific element. Below is the code for scrolling:

```
def self.swipe_to (programme)
   begin
   scroll_to(programme)
   rescue
     puts 'unable to find ' + programme
     return false
   end
   return true
end
```

The scrolling works fine however, the issue is the app scrolls to the programme but as soon the programme is found, the app scrolls back to the top of the list.
And then an error is thrown saying element could not be found.

Has anybody seen similar kind of issue before? Is there any way to stop scrolling as soon as programme is found? I just want to stop the scrolling back to the top as soon as programme is found. Please help.

Comment: did you check the visibility of the element?

Comment: Initially the element is not visible, that's why I have to scroll. Once the element is visible, the scrolling stops but then scrolling starts automatically in reverse order and stops at the top of the page. At this point, the element becomes invisible again.

Comment: check if my answer will help you

Answer (score 0):

I created a method to scroll to an element that is not on screen yet, because `scroll_to` was not working for me. This methos scrolls to any element on screen even if its not visible yet

```
def scroll_to_element(class_name, element_name)
  ele_by_json(typeArray: [class_name], onlyVisible: false, name: {target: element_name, substring: false, insensitive: false})
end
```

Comment: I am trying to use your method but I am getting undefined method `ele_by_json' error (NoMethodError). Please note, I am trying to automate Android app. I have also tried "ele_by_json_visible_contains" after searching on internet but no luck :(

Comment: oh `ele_by_json` is only for ios, but you can try another methods listed here https://github.com/appium/ruby_lib/blob/master/lib/appium_lib/android/element/generic.rb

Comment: I tried find and find exact but the problem is that it is finding only those elements which are currently visible on the screen. If the element is not visible on the screen then NoSuchElementError is observed.

Comment: when I manually scroll the app so that element is visible then the find method works fine. But I need the scroll to happen by automation. Scroll_to works fine but it scrolls to the element and then scrolls back to the top and hence the search fails :(

Comment: @Anshul Is there any way you found a solution or work around to the problem? I am using appium_lib and I am still having the same issue. scroll_to or scroll_to_exact, keeps scrolling aimlessly

Comment: im sorry for the late reply, i didnt get notified, i checked and this method only work on ios, unfortunatelly i cannot try it on android, but did you guys check this page? maybe `scroll_to_exact` will do what you want https://github.com/appium/ruby_lib/blob/master/lib/appium_lib/android/element/generic.rb

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me :

```
def scrollTo el_start, el_end
  #get element coordinates start
  el_start = $driver.find_element(:id, el_start)
  screen_x_start = el_start.location.x
  screen_y_start = el_start.location.y
  #get element coordinates end
  el_end = $driver.find_element(:id, el_end)
  screen_x_end = el_end.location.x
  screen_y_end = el_end.location.y
  Appium::TouchAction.new.swipe(start_x: screen_x_start, start_y: screen_y_start, delta_x: screen_x_end, delta_y: screen_y_end).perform
end
```